# Bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $C[0,1]$, space of all continuous complex valued functions defined on $[0,1]$, and $f_{t_0}\in C[0,1]$, a function defined as
$$f_{t_0}(x)=x(t_0).$$
Then, $f_{t_0}$ is a bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$.

My question is : If $f\in C[0,1]$ is a bounded linear functional, then $f=f_{t_0}$?

In other words, Is there exists a bounded linear functional $f$ on $C[0,1]$ other than $f_{t_0}$?

Comment: What about $f=f_0+f_1$???

Comment: Twice you write that  a bounded linear functional  on $C[0,1]$ is an element of $C[0,1]$. That's nonsense - what's the definition of "linear functional on $C[0,1]$"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionals you mentioned cover a certain type of functionals: multiplicative linear functionals.

In general, if you consider any regular, complete, finite complex measure $\lambda$ on $[0,1]$, you will get a linear functional $\phi$ on $C[0,1]$ which acts in the following way

$$\phi (f)= \int_{[0,1]} f d\lambda.$$

Conversely, any bounded linear functional $\phi$ on $C[0,1]$ has the above mentioned form (i.e., an expression in terms of a measure). It is called Riesz representation theorem. See *Rudin's Real and Complex analysis*. Note that your functional can be expresses by the *Dirac measure* at $t_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For instance,$$F(f)=\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx,$$assuming that the distance on $C[0,1]$ is $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\bigl\lvert f(x)-g(x)\bigr\rvert$.